# How to avoid newly downloaded iOS apps to be automatically downloaded in another device

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

Say I download App A in my iPhone. The app will be automatically appeared in my iPad. How to prevent that from happening? I want to download separately because different devices have different needs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In each devices settings, you can disable automatic downloads in Settings -> iTunes & App Store and then disable "Apps" in the "Automatic Downloads" section. This will stop apps from automatically being downloaded onto your iPad. You will need to install the specific apps you want on the device manually through the App Store.